# trying to install teamspeak3

Tags: software-installation, teamspeak

So, I followed some threads created here but nothing solved my problem.
I downloaded the 64bit version of teamspeak3, and did this:

1. Opened terminal
2. Went to the folder where my teamspeak was downloaded (desktop, so I did cd Desktop)
3. did this command: `chmod u+x ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run`
4. Then this: `./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run`

OK, pressed `Q` and `yes`, installed and the system created a new folder.

The problem starts here: when I try to open `ts3client_linux_amd64`, nothing happens. I already changed the propriets to allow executing the file as a program but nothing seems to happen.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Teamspeak. Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo cp TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run /opt
cd /opt
sudo chmod +x TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run
sudo TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86-3.0.12.run
```

The script creates a folder with the name `TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86`. Start the client with:

```
TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86/ts3client_runscript.sh
```

---

Create a desktop file:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/teamspeak.desktop
```

Add the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Teamspeak 3 Client
Comment=Teamspeak 3 Client
Icon=teamspeak3
Exec=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_x86/ts3client_runscript.sh
Terminal=false
Categories=Games;
StartupWMClass=Teamspeak
```

The entry `Icon=teamspeak3` you need to replace it with an icon of your choice. In my icon theme is an icon for Teamspeak 3.